# Using androidx.navigation.ui in a master/detail flow

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I have made an app which uses the standard `DrawerLayout` template, however when trying to adapt the layout to a master/detail layout for larger displays I have stumbled across some odd behavior. and I'm not sure how to keep the interactions/behavior the same between transitions.

The layout for mobile is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_layout"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The layout for tablet is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:elevation="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/nav_host_fragment"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_layout"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_layout"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The included toolbar is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" >

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

The MainActivity.kt is;

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

private var mTablet = false
private lateinit var navController: NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

     val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout? = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    if (drawerLayout == null) {
        mTablet = true
    }

    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    val navSet = setOf(
        R.id.nav_journal, R.id.nav_reports, R.id.nav_calendar,
        R.id.nav_templates, R.id.nav_copyright, R.id.nav_instructions,
        R.id.nav_settings, R.id.nav_social, R.id.nav_support
    )

    if (mTablet == false) {
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navSet, drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    } else {
        //TODO setup action bar with Nav Controller
        //appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navSet, toolbar)
        //val navigationView: ViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.navigation_fragment)
    }

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_settings)
        }
        R.id.action_support -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_support)
        }
        R.id.action_social -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_social)
        }
        R.id.action_instructions -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_instructions)
        }
        R.id.action_copyright -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_copyright)
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
}
```

The navigation xml has no hierarchy to it, it is just a collection of fragments which i will exand upon later.

The problem is that the master/detail flow doesn't have a `DrawerLayout` and so it isn't possible to keep the functionality of the toolbar changing to the title of the currently displayed fragment without using `AppBarConfiguration(navSet, drawerLayout)`.

I realize that Kotlin is null safe and the code will work regardless, however it seems like an oversight to force people to accept nullpointer exceptions.

I've been looking at the documentation to find a way to use a different constructor method that accepts either a toolbar object (since that is what is being updated) or a different kind of layout and haven't been able to find anything. Are we supposed to accept the less than ideal code or is there another solution that im missing?

I am writing my app in Kotlin with Android Studio.